# Way to add all the missing imports in one go in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Let's say, initially I have a screen which currently contains all the UI as well as the logic.
But now I want to separate the UI and the logic into two different files, and maybe some UI too.

**Question:**
Is there any extension or a terminal command that I can execute so that all the missing files will get imported?

NOTE: I know I can just copy all the imports from the original file, but then I would have also copied some unwanted imports. I just want to import the filed that are needed.

Comment: HI, have you found a way

Comment: Nope, I haven't yet.

Comment: its really strange I have to do it all manually!!!